# how to prove that $\big \lfloor \frac np\big \rfloor+\big \lfloor \frac n{p^2}\big \rfloor+\big \lfloor \frac n{p^3}\big \rfloor+\cdots≤\frac n{p-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Prove:  $$\Big \lfloor \frac np\Big \rfloor+\Big \lfloor \frac n{p^2}\Big \rfloor+\Big \lfloor \frac n{p^3}\Big \rfloor+\cdots≤\frac n{p-1}$$

I tried to calculate both sides with floor function again.when we do that left side of the equation is still same while the right side $\frac n{p-1}$ becomes $\Big \lfloor \frac {n}{p-1}\Big \rfloor$ which is a integer.but i dont know what to do with it

Comment: Well, what is $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{p^k}$?

Comment: 1/p-1 but its not enough

Comment: Well, it is most of the way. @Creedance

Comment: Why is it not enough?

Comment: So you sayin n[1/p^k]=[n/p^k]

Comment: Nobody said that.

Comment: Nobody is saying that.  But $\lfloor x\rfloor ≤ x$ for any $x$ so....

Comment: Oooooh i'm sory i only thinked about complex stuff sory got it

Comment: Can $|p| \leq 1$ ?? If p=1 it's obviously wrong since the RHS is undefined...

Comment: @Lelouch The series converges if and only if $|p|>1$.

Comment: Well the OP does not give any hypotheses on $p$ so it should be clarified.

Comment: I edited accordingly to the likely framework of estimating p-adic valuation of a factorial.

Comment: @AndreaMarino I have performed a rollback as nowhere in the question the primality of p is implied. I believe that one should not change the basic assumptions of a question in order to fit a particular interpretation. Here, for example, the top answer works perfectly fine for composite p.

Comment: In some circles, writing $p$ means it is a (positive) prime number.

Comment: @insipidintegrator: it's not necessary, but the question was ill-posed from the beginning and I tried to reverse-engineer what the OP had in mind. I was puzzled by the discussion around $|p| > 1 $ since I thought it was integral. There is no need for $n$ integer neither. However, the only solution to the problem "what OP had in mind? Where did he take the problem?" is the OP itself.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor \leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{n}{p^k} = \frac{n}{p-1}\;\;\;\;,\;\; \text{ for } |p|>1$$

Answer (score 3):

An alternative perspective on the proof which works only when $p$ is a prime number and $n$ a nonnegative integer can be seen by [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) for the power of $p$ dividing $n!$, written in terms of the $p$-adic absolute value as,

$$v_p(n!) = \sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$

This has the alternate form in terms of the sum of digits of $n$ written in base $p$ function $s_p(n)$,

$$\sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor = \frac{n-s_p(n)}{p-1}$$

Since for nonnegative integers $n$ we have $s_p(n)\ge 0$:

$$\sum_{k \ge 1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor \le \frac{n}{p-1}$$

This proof is certainly less efficient than the one given by Andreas, but has the nice side effect of giving us a simple upper bound on the power of $p$ dividing $n!$.

Comment: I feel like Legendre's formula is a generalization of the given inequality, so it seems like cheating a bit

Comment: @AndreaMarino I believe that the _question_ is a generalisation of Legendre’s formula, not the other  way round. I am open to hearing about your stance though.

Comment: @Merosity thank you for this answer! I almost made a new question about the number-theoretic interpretation because I didn’t know the formula about sum of digits. Upvoted.

Comment: @insipidintegrator You're welcome! Even more concretely as a number theoretic consequence, you can use this to determine the p-adic radius of convergence of the exponential $\exp(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ (which is $p^{-\frac{1}{p-1}}$).

Comment: @insipidintegrator: that's how I see the thing. The inequality shows such p-adic valuation (given in infinite sum formula) is at most $n/(p-1)$. Extra effort is necessary to find how sharp is the inequality, and what is the precise defect. To find the precise defect you have to write $n$ in base $p$ and explicitly evaluate the summands in terms of the digits, resulting in the legendre formula. It's a harder computation! But I agree, it is very interesting and I love this kind of result. Not sure what's your point of view!

Comment: @AndreaMarino What I meant to say was that this interpretation restricts p to primes only, while the original question extends to all real p such that |p| >1.